# Put list items into another list without transforming into list of list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have code like below:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 500), np.linspace(-5, 5, 500))

Z = model.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

However, my code should be flexible enough to handle one feature and two feature case. Therefore, I plan to change my code into below:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 500), np.linspace(-5, 5, 500))

npc = [xx.ravel()]* feature_number

Z = model.decision_function(np.c_[npc])
```

Unfortunately, npc is already a list, and when I decide to put it into `np.c_[npc]` it become double layer list. Any idea to use the dynamic method but still perform like the initial method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand. It seems all you need to do is just tile your array. You can use `np.tile` -

```
npc = np.tile(xx.ravel(), feature_number)
```

`npc` will be repeated `feature_number` of times, and will remain a 1D array.

Comment: I got a warning on Pycharm stating Expected type 'Union[ndarray,  iterable]', got int instead  at feature_number there. However, it works. Is that fine?

Comment: @MervynLee PyCharm seems to be spitting out a type hint based warning at you, but if it works fine, then don't worry about it.